# Polynomial coefficients tensor generalization

Tags: polynomials, tensors, tensor-rank

Let $\mathbb{R}_k[x_1, \dots x_n]$ denote the ring of polynomials of degree $k=0, 1 \dots d$.

A polynomial is said *homogeneous* if the non-zero terms all have the same degree. Any *homogeneous* polynomial can be written as

$$p(x) = \sum_{i_1, \dots , i_k =1}^n \textbf{W}_{i_1, \dots, i_k}\, x_{i_1} \dots x_{i_k}$$

where $\textbf{W}_{i_1, \dots , i_k}$ is its **coefficient tensor**. I'm having some issues to fully understand these tensor generalization of polynomial coefficient.

if I consider $p \in \mathbb{R}[x_1, \dots , x_n]$ I usually write it as

$$a_nx^{n} + a_{n-1}x^{n-1} + \dots + a_1x + a_0\, \, \, , \, a_i \in \mathbb{R}$$.

So how should I generalize the coefficients belonging to a higher order tensor? I think I'm getting confused between the rank of the tensor and the degree of polynomial...

I'm trying to do an example, let's say that $k=2$ and $n=3$ so we have

\begin{align}
\sum_{i_1, i_2=1}^3 W_{i_1i_2}x_{i_1}x_{i_2}&= \sum_{i_1=1}^3\left(W_{i_11}x_{i_1}x_{1} + W_{i_12}x_{i_1}x_{2}+W_{i_13}x_{i_1}x_{3}\right)\\
&=W_{11}x_{1}x_{1} + W_{12}x_{1}x_{2}+W_{13}x_{1}x_{3}+W_{21}x_{2}x_{1} + W_{22}x_{2}x_{2}+W_{23}x_{2}x_{3}
\end{align}

So in this case $\textbf{W} \in \mathbb{R}^{2 \times 3}$ so it is a 2-rank tensor while $n$ is the degree of polynomial.. but how does this thing work more in detail? ^^

Should I assume now that the degree of each monomial is 3?

Why the $\textbf{W}$ shape results in being tensor rank $\times$ polynomial degree?

Many thanks,

James

Comment: It looks like these are noncommutative polynomial rings (i.e. noncommuting variables)? You’re missing three terms in your example, namely the ones with $x_3$ as the first variable factor. So $\mathbf W$ should be of dimensions $3\times3$, and in general $n^k$.

Comment: $w_{ij}x_ix_j=w_{11} x_1^2 + w_{12} x_1 x_2 + w_{21} x_1 x_2 + w_{22} x_2^2 + w_{13} x_1 x_3 + w_{31} x_1 x_3 + 
 w_{23} x_2 x_3 + w_{32} x_2 x_3 + w_{33} x_3^2$

Comment: (I assume $x_1x_2=x_2x_1$; The space of symmetric tensors of order r on a finite-dimensional vector space V is naturally isomorphic to the dual of the space of homogeneous polynomials of degree r on V. Over fields of characteristic zero, the graded vector space of all symmetric tensors can be naturally identified with the symmetric algebra on V.